# How can I get my PCA plot graph to display?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I'm trying to build a PCA graph and after getting the graph for some reason I'm unable to get my graph to display. How can I fix this issue.

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('ANNCitydata.csv')
# load dataset into Pandas DataFrame
X1 = X.drop(['ID','City'], axis=1)
y = pd.read_csv('ANNCitydata.csv', usecols=["City"])
```

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X1)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
```

```
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, y[['City']]], axis = 1)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ['City']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['City'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 1']
               , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 2']
               , c = color
               , s = 100)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

So I pretty much get a blank graph

Comment: Two reasons: the first is that your loop stops at the first iteration because len(targets)=1 while len(colors)=3 hence zip stops prematurely. Second because I guess in the column city you have no City named 'City'

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Hard Core. Just modified your code. It should work, but not able to test since I got no original data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ('City1', 'City2', 'City3')  ## Specify city names
colors = ('r', 'g', 'b')


for data, target, color in zip(finalDf,targets,colors):
    x, y = data.iloc[:,0:2]
    ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=100, label=target)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I get an error at "x,y = data" stating ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @user11860705 I am sorry I missed the third column 'city'. Try this: x, y = data.iloc[:,0:2]